# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shops", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an Ecommerce app, where every user can create their own shop. The association between user and shop should be

```
user has_one shop
shop belongs_to user
```

And so far, the user who created a shop is working perfectly. But for those who didn't, It show me an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shops", :id=>nil},  missing required keys: [:id]
```

In my `shops_controller.rb`

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_shop, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_user

  def show
    if current_user.shop.blank?
        render 'new'
    else
        @items = Item.where(shop_id: @shop.id)   
    end
  end

  def index    
    @shops = Shop.all.order("created at DESC")    
  end

  def new
    @shop = current_user.build_shop
  end

  def create 
    @shop = current_user.build_shop(shop_params)
    if @shop.save
        session[:shop_id] = @shop.id
       flash[:success] = "Creating item success"
       redirect_to @shop, notice: 'success'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

private 

  def shop_params
    params.require(:shop).permit( :name , :user_id)
  end

  def find_store
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_user
    @user = UrStore.find_by(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

In `application.html.erb`

```
 <% if user_signed_in?%>
   <%= link_to "profile", user_path(current_user.id) %>
   <% if current_user.shop == nil %>
     <li><%= link_to "Your shop", new_shop_path %></li>
   <% else %>
     <li><%= link_to "Your shop", shop_path(current_user.shop.id)%></li>    
   <% end %>   
 <% end %>
```

The `current_user` is generated automatically by gem 'devise'.

The error occured when I click on "Your Shop", and the error only happen with user who doesn't create his/her shop

in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
root 'static_pages#home'
as :user do
  get "signin" => "devise/sessions#new"
  post "signin" => "devise/sessions#create"
  delete "signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
resources :shops
```

This line raised the error:

```
<li><%= link_to "Your Shop",shop_path(current_user.shop.id)%></li>
```

I'm looking for solutions to solve this problem :-)

Comment: Where are you clicking to raise this error ?

Comment: let me edit the question

Comment: Can you show us your `routes.rb` file ?

Comment: sorry for making you wait, I updated my question

Comment: Well looks like there's no error, can we have the full error trace ? It should be pointing at a particular line.

Comment: I think I found it, look at my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to `new_shop_path` your controller action `new` seems to build a user shop :

```
@shop = current_user.build_shop
```

So from here `current_user.shop != nil`

But as it's not saved at that moment, this shop has no `id`. So in your view it goes in the `else` as shop is not nil but then there no `id` and it raises an error.

```
<% if current_user.shop == nil %>
  <li><%= link_to "Your shop", new_shop_path %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Your shop", shop_path(current_user.shop.id)%></li>    
<% end %>
```

change it to :

```
<% if !current_user.shop || !current_user.shop.id %>
  <li><%= link_to "Your shop", new_shop_path %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Your shop", shop_path(current_user.shop.id)%></li>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: It was supposed to be `current_user.shop&.new_record?`, that takes care of the undefined error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want redirect instead of render and also make sure shop is persisted to the database.

```
def show
  if current_user.shop&.persisted?
    redirect_to :new
  else
    @items = Item.where(shop_id: @shop.id)   
  end
end
```

Also in your view you can do this using safe navigation and use `.persisted?` since you care more about that the `shop.id` and this logic makes more sense than the other way around.

```
<% if current_user.shop&.persisted? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Your shop", shop_path(current_user.shop.id)%></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Your shop", new_shop_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried the redirect_to but it still the same error

Comment: See updated answer based on the previous answer. Both should help you and make your code more readable.